# What is a "moment" in mathematics, and what does it mean?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics

This is a general question. I would like a better conceptual understanding of what a moment is, it's meaning, and it's applications (not just in probability).

I already looked at Wikipedia, but I still didn't understand it. Could someone explain it in simpler terms?

Comment: It sometimes means an average.

Comment: In colloquial terms, it's a way of measuring the spread of the data set. If the value of a high degree moment is large, it means that the data set is spread far from the origin.

Comment: @CameronWilliams 
Could you elaborate more? Potentially turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

In some generality, given a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$, point $a \in \mathbb R^n$, and multi-index $\alpha$, the corresponding moment of $\mu$ 
 is

$$\int (x - a)^\alpha \; d\mu(x) $$